# How to find '\' from a pandas dataframe in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, database, dataframe

I used the following code:

```
remove_image=[]
for n,i in enumerate(data['class']):
    if i == str("\"):
        print(i,n)
        remove_image.append(n)
```

I got the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-109-3dce64dd25ea>", line 3
    if i == str("\"):
                     ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BPY6.png)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use " \ \ " (Two backslashes).
The first one is to escape the character.
"\" needs to be escaped in Python.